# Compute $E(Y_t^2)$ with $Y_t =\int_{0}^{t}(e^{-as} \sigma \int_{0}^{s} e^{au} dW_{u})ds$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider the process, $Y_t =\int_{0}^{t}(e^{-as} \sigma \int_{0}^{s} e^{au} dW_{u})ds$. To compute the variance of this process, I need to compute $E[(\int_{0}^{t}(e^{-as} \sigma \int_{0}^{s} e^{au} dW_{u})ds)^2]$. If $dW_u$ was the outer integral then we could apply Ito's Isometry? But how would one change the order of integration here?

Comment: $$Y_t =\int_{0}^{t}g(t,u)dW_{u}\qquad g(t,u)=\sigma e^{au}\int_u^te^{-as}ds=\ldots\implies E(Y_t^2)=\int_0^tg(t,u)^2du$$

Comment: @Did I don't understand how you are changing the order of integration. I would think it would look something like: $\int_{0}^{s} \int_{0}^{t} ... ds dW_u$

Comment: Not sure what $\int_0^s\cdots ds$ in your comment would refer to. Anyway, the domain of integration is $$0<s<t\qquad 0<u<s$$ which is also $$0<u<t\qquad u<s<t$$

Comment: Ah, you changed the suggestion, but now what is $s$ in $\int_0^s\cdots dW_u$?